# How to grab html using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
#<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.samplewebsite.com/image/5434553/' />

#I am trying to grab the text in href

image = str(Soup)

image_re = re.compile('\<link rel=\'cononical\' href=')

image_pat = re.findall(image_re, image)

print image_pa

#>> []

#Thanks!
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit: This uses the BeautifulSoup package, which I thought I saw in the previous version of this question.

Edit: More straightforward is this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(document)
links = soup.findAll('link', rel='canonical')
for link in links:
    print link['href']
```

Instead of all that, you can use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(document)
links = soup("link")
for link in links:
    if "rel" in link and link["rel"] == 'canonical':
        print link["href"]
```

Comment: +1, way cool. What libraries do you need and/or what modules do you need to import for this to work?

Comment: I'm not the one who posted the question (and in addition I didn't see any BeautifulSoup references in the version of the question I was looking at). I can look BeautifulSoup up but I thought future newbies might find more information useful if you added it to comments or your answer.

Comment: there are no BS references, Soup can be of type that has __str__() ;). But yeah, one should use html parser for that.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had seen BeautifulSoup listed in the original question (which was edited). Anyway, the BeautifulSoup library is awesome for parsing/searching HTML and XML documents. The documentation is at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

Comment: even easier way would be to just use `result = [tag['href'] for tag in BeautifulSoup(doc).findAll('link',  rel='canonical')]` intead of for/if. BS.findAll() can put restrictions on attribute values.

Comment: @soulcheck Agreed, but for questions like this I usually avoid list comprehensions because it's not clear if the submitter understands what they are/how to use them.

Comment: @jknupp the point was more about restrictions on attributes :)

Comment: @soulcheck Ah, missed that part. You're right, that would be clearer

Answer (score 0):

Use two regular expressions:

```
import re
link_tag_re = re.compile(r'(<link[^>]*>')
# capture all link tags in your text with it. Then for each of those, use:
href_capture = re.compile(r'href\s*=\s*(\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*")')
```

The first regex will capture the entire `<link>` tag; the second one will look for `href="something"` or `href='something'`.

In general, though, you should probably use an XML parser for HTML, even though this problem is a perfectly regular language problem. They're far simpler to use for this sort of thing and are less likely to cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTML parser such as `lxml.html` or `BeautifulSoup`. But if you only want to grab the `href` of a single `link`, you could use a simple regex too:

```
re.findall(r"href=(['\"])([^\1]*)\1", url)
```

Comment: How would you do it with lxml?

Answer (score 0):

You're better of using a proper HTML parser on the data, but if you really want to go down this route then the following will do it:

```
>>> data = "... <link rel='canonical' href='http://www.samplewebsite.com/image/5434553/' /> ..."
>>>
>>> re.search("<link[^>]+?rel='canonical'[^>]+?href='([^']+)", x).group(1)
'http://www.samplewebsite.com/image/5434553/'
>>>
```

I also notice that your HTML uses single quotes rather than double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the regex to match the example html you've given:

```
<link rel='canonical' href='(\S+)'
```

But I'm not sure if regex is the right tool. This regex will fail when using double quotes (or no quotes) for the values. Or if rel and href are turned around.

I'd recommend using something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to find and collect all rel canonical href values.